# Triggered Sends and Data Extension

Tags: dataextensions, triggered-send

I'm just a beginner with Marketing Cloud and we are trying to send triggered email using "triggered sends" under Interactions tab. I was able to create Triggered Send Data Extension that is shown under "Triggered Sends" Data Extensions. However, if I'm not mistaken, this is the data extension which should contain all the contacts to which the triggered email is send to, am I right? Or should my contacts be on a list? In brief, I would like to know what is the correct way to have my contacts, on a list or data extension? And if data extension is the way to go, how do I add contacts to a Triggered Sends Data Extension or create a Triggered Sends Data Extension with contacts? I'm very confused with this all so all help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the "Triggered Send Data Extension" represents is a data extension for which contacts are immediately sent an email once they are added to it. It should be empty to start off with, but as your triggers start running, it gets populated.

For more information on this, please visit [HERE](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/)

Comment: I still unfortunately don't know how to create a trigger for example if I would like to send a welcome email to a new newsletter subscriber. Then the trigger would be a new subscriber on the list. How can I get my empty data extension to be populated with this subscriber?

Comment: @RachelT. Have you read the hyperlink in the answer? The full guide is there

Comment: For future reference, one simple breakdown (for transactional email sends) is:  you take the `ExternalKey` of the TriggeredSend DataExtension and the `CustomerKey` of an email template (you can create both via the web UI). Then you relate them together by creating a `SendDefinition` (which *must* be created via an API call). To send an email, you make another API call with, basically, an object that contains the `definitionKey` , an email, and some other data.

You'll have to hunt down the specifics, but that's the basic flow for transactional email sends via REST.